# Removed permissions are still showing in play console

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-play-console

I have removed a few permissions from my manifest file and tried to upload it in google play. But I'm still able to see the permission which I have removed earlier from the manifest file. Is it because of any hidden permissions? 
Thanks in advance. I'll post my manifest file in comments if someone wants to check the code.

Comment: May be you have used third party library which contains those permissions

Answer (score 0):

post your manifest file. also check whether you are using any run time permission in any java file